# How can I upload files to firebase's cloud storage with a path using the admin sdk?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

There's not much on the firebase documentation explaining how to upload files with a path when using the firebase admin sdk for google cloud storage.

I've looked at [firebase's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_a_default_bucket) and it specifies that I can create a bucket and that I should refer to [google clouds documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) for further help.

Then they also show how to create another storage bucket plus links leading to [API Reference Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/), which again shows you how to create another storage bucket, but at least this time there is a table of code examples to refer from. The [files](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/samples/files.js) link at the table shows a repo example that has

```
// Uploads a local file to the bucket
  storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .upload(filename)
    .then(() => {
      console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

which was helpful as I was able to upload a file with admin using it.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com"
});
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
bucket.upload('local/file/path').then(data => {
    console.log('upload success');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('error uploading to storage', err);
});
```

Although I'm still at a loss with how to specify a path as this just puts it at the top level of my firebase storage bucket. Anyone know how I can specify a path to nest my files deeper with the api?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please refer to the [API documentation for the upload() method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/Bucket#upload).  You can see that upload takes a second parameter called "options" to describe the upload.  The options object may have a property called `destination` to describe where the file should be uploaded.

> (string or File)
>
> The place to save your file. If given a string, the file will be
>   uploaded to the bucket using the string as a filename. When given a
>   File object, your local file will be uploaded to the File object's
>   bucket and under the File object's name. Lastly, when this argument is
>   omitted, the file is uploaded to your bucket using the name of the
>   local file or the path of the url relative to it's domain.

So, you can use it like this:

```
bucket.upload('local/file/path', { destination: 'location/in/bucket' })
```

Comment: I want to save a JSON as a file. How can I create that file and then uploading it? fs.writeFileSync() is not working as it's read only. Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'mynewfile3.txt'

Comment: says page not found :/